# CSS Overflow, the scroll bar appears at the bottom, how can I get a scroll bar at the top?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a box wider then it's parent, so I set:

```
Overflow: auto;
```

Now the box is really tall, something like 2000 pixels, way off screen. The box has a fixed width of 1100px with the child box now a lot bigger. The scroll bar to scroll right or left is at the bottom. How can I get a scroll bar at the top? I'm open to CSS or jQuery.

Comment: I'd worry that any custom solution you find isn't going to be accessible. Try navigating the scrolling with the keyboard alone on all proposed solutions, to make sure someone that can't reliably use a mouse is okay with your scroll implementation.

Comment: Accessibility isn't a problem for these few intranet users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) you can add a custom scroll in any position you wish

Answer (score 4):

Browsers always put the scrollbars bottom and right. The only ways round this are to use a non-native scrollbar implementation - such as flash or a custom js that mimics a scrollbar.

As a rule of thumb, established user interface patterns such as this should be left alone - people know that scrollbars are at the bottom and the right.

Comment: Right. I understand, hence the question. I'm looking for a solution to get it at the top.

Comment: To whoever voted me down - please add a comment explaining why. There is nothing incorrect in my answer.

Comment: The question is not why is it doing it, but how can I get it to behave the way I need it to; that's why I voted you down. This is something the user wants. You are correct that there is nothing incorrect, however that is not the answer to the question I am looking for.